# Initializing Direct3D vectors

Tags: vector, direct3d9, initializing

I am using this to initialize Directx vectors.

```
LPD3DXVECTOR3 sat_map[] = 
{
    { -1.5f,  0.0f,  1.5f},
    {  1.5f, -1.5f,  1.5f},
};
```

Even when I try without doing an array, I always get the same error:

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float' to 'LPD3DXVECTOR3'

I tried doing doubles, but I got a similar error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPD3DXVECTOR3` is a *pointer* to a `D3DXVECTOR3`, and you can't initialize a pointer with a structure (only with a pointer to a structure). Therefore, you just want

```
D3DXVECTOR3 sat_map[] = 
{
    { -1.5f,  0.0f,  1.5f},
    {  1.5f, -1.5f,  1.5f},
};
```

or

```
D3DXVECTOR3 v1 = { -1.5f,  0.0f,  1.5f};
D3DXVECTOR3 v2 = {  1.5f, -1.5f,  1.5f};
LPD3DXVECTOR3 sat_map[] = { &v1, &v2 };
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use this:  D3DXVECTOR3 sat_map1( -1.5f,  0.0f,  1.5f);  I discovered also that vectors must be initialized by a constructor.  I got it working now, thanks so much!